# Most efficient way to change synthetic partition key values

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with thousands of documents all of which have a synthetic partition key property like:

`partitionKey: ‘some-document-related-value’`

now i need to change values for  `partitionKey`. of course, it takes recreation of documents in order to do so but i am wondering what is the most efficient/straightforward way to do it?

1. should i use azure function with cosmosdbtrigger? (set to start feed from begining)
2. change feed processor?
3. some other way?

i’m looking for quickest solution thats still reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change feed is a common way to migrate data from one container to another. Another simple option may be to use [Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSource) where you build your new partition key in the select statement.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: although Data migration tool might work, there is a bit too much logic in converting old to new partition key values to fit into select statements so i believe i'll go with functions & cosmosdbtrigger. thanks!